# how is addtodate interpreted in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

In Matlab, what does it mean to add 6 months? How is this interpreted?  Would it be the same day but in the 7th month from today? i,e. If it's 10/15, then this would give 4/15?  How would I achieve this in python?

```matlab
addtodate(datenum(date), 6, 'month')
```

Answer (score 1):

[from the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html)

```
adds quantity Q to the indicated date field F of a scalar serial date number D
```

So yes, it just increments the month by 6. You can manage this in Python using [the DateTime library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Comment: what if it was 8/31? what is 6 months from then mean?  I'm looking at the addtodate.m but they don't address these

Comment: Good question. I agree, the documentation isn't particularly clear. I see only two possibilities: 1) ask MathWorks, 2) do some experiments to figure it out.

Comment: Matlab automatically adjusts for [carryover](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/carryover-in-date-vectors-and-strings.html).